# В какую сторону при каких обстоятельствах округлять midpoint при бинарном поиске?

Tags: javascript, python, алгоритм

Изучаю алгоритм бинарной сортировки, в книге (Грокаем Алгоритмы), в других описаниях вскользь говорится, что мол mid = (low + high) / 2 (с округлением в меньшую сторону). Я не понимаю, почему делают именно floor округление. 

**Вопрос**: можно ли использовать ceil округление? Если да, то в каких случаях выбирать ceil, а в каких floor? Прочитал, что есть две разновидности этого алгоритма для нахождения первого и последнего вхождения числа в массив, возможно в этих случаях это принципиально(если не сложно можете написать код того и другого)? 

В прямом смысле, первый алгоритм после линейного который начал изучать, поэтому, пожалуйста, аккуратнее с терминами. Спасибо всем кто ответит, ссылки на статьи, примеры, разъяснения - все изучу :)

Comment: Это всё исторически сложилось. `floor` быстрее, реализуется с помощью битового сдвига. Можно даже делить `(1/3 : 2/3)` всё равно будет логарифмическая сложность.

Comment: @AlexGlebe я был очень за, что это просто так сложилось исторически, но цитирую: "Существуют две модификации этого алгоритма для поиска первого и последнего вхождения. Все зависит от того, как выбирается средний элемент: округлением в меньшую или большую сторону. В первом случае средний элемент относится к левой части массива, а во втором - к правой." - и вот тут я как взял, так и ничего не понял в два раза больше) Т.к. после этого отрывка не было примеров кода.

Comment: Поиску элемента в отсортированном массиве может быть нужно крайние одинаковые значения, а для сортировки - нет. Всё зависит от вашей задачи. Можете искать оба края - это ваше право.

Answer (score 2):

Неважно в какую сторону округлять. Главное чтобы сохранялся инвариант f(l) != f(r)